# Making a general container search function

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers

I want to be able to search any standard container with a function. For example, if I have an `std::vector`, or an `std::map`, I want to see if it contains a certain element.

I've been using this code:

```
template<typename T, typename valueType>
bool contains(T vec, valueType element) {
    return std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), element) != vec.end();
}
```

It doesn't work on `std::map`s though, it doesn't compile if I pass the function a map, which is something I want it to do. Any way I can do this?

Comment: `std::find` doesn't accept the iterators that come from `map::begin()` and `map::end()`. ie, It fails to compile.

Comment: Depends on the iterators that a container supports.  Have you tried `std::find` or `std::lower_bound`?

Comment: I don't understand.  The `std::map` is a data structure that is optimized for finding the `key` field of a `key,value` pair.  Please clarify what you need and what you want.

Comment: `std::find()` only requires input iterators. `std::map` provides a stronger concept (bidirectional iterators) and `std::find()` definitely works with map's iterators!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: of course, you may need to match an element on different criteria than the map's key (admittedly, I'd expect `std::find_if()` to be used in this case...).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You're right, I didn't make it clear. I want to be able to search the keys of the map.

Comment: You would lose the benefits of using `O(1)` or `O(log n)` containers this way.

Comment: @BWG so.. if its a [sequence container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (vector, deck, list, etc) you want to search by *value*, and if its an [associative container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (map, etc) you want to search by *key*? or was that not fully considered yet?

Comment: @BWG: provide a complete example which doesn't compile. I'd suspect that your problem aren't the iterators but rather that you try to compare a key to a `std::map<K, V>::value_type` which is of type `std::pair<K const, V>`, not `K` or `V`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl This does not compile if I call it using a `map` as the container and a `map` key as the value.

Comment: BTW, time-complexity clearly doesn't matter to this code, **at all**: the container is passed by value, i.e., the best time complexity to be achieved is `O(n)` anyway. The `find()` is the cheap part...!

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I did consider it, but for some reason I was thinking that the keys were the values.

Comment: @BWG: that's just as I suspected, no? Well, the objects obtained from `*it` for a `std::map<K, V>` is of type `std::pair<K const, V>` and **not** `K`. If you want to match just the key you'll need to project the map value, e.g., by using `std::find_if()` with a suitable predicate along the lines of `[=](value_type& v){ return v.key == element; }`. Obviously, you should probably specialize your `contains()` function for the case the container contains a `find()` member and use that one.

Comment: @BWG You just said a few lines earlier "I want to be able to search the keys of the map.". The keys of a map are not the maps "values" The *pairs* of a map are its values. You can certainly manufacture a `std::pair<>`, but I suspect it is pointless if you already know the keyed-value to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you should probably have two versions of your `contains()` function:

1. One which leverages a `find()` member on the first argument taking an object of the second argument as parameter. This way, an `O(log n)` or `O(1)` (expected) version of `find()` provided by associative containers is used.
2. A fall-back version which does a linear search on the sequence.

It is probably desirable to have the compiler figure out which version to use. As a result the code would look something like this:

```
struct container_find {
    template <typename C, typename K>
    static std::true_type test(decltype(std::declval<C const&>().find(std::declval<K const&>()))*);
    template <typename C, typename K>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template <typename C, typename K>
typename std::enable_if<!decltype(container_find::test<C, K>(0))::value, bool>::type
contains(C const& c, K const& k) {
    return c.end() != std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), k); 
}

template <typename C, typename K>
typename std::enable_if<decltype(container_find::test<C, K>(0))::value, bool>::type
contains(C const& c, K const& k) {
    return c.end() != c.find(k);
}
```

The class `container_find` is simply a helper which is used to detect if the container type provides a usable version of `find()`. The result is used with `std::enable_if<...>` to enable the appropriate version of `contains()`. The implementation of `contains()` also avoid copying the container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that should be perfect. I'm new to conditional template compilation (or whatever it's called) so I'm gonna try and decipher everything that's happening, but I get the basic idea.